# How to get localized fields during csv import in pimcore

Tags: pimcore

I am not getting option for data mapping for localized fields in my class during csv import

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the onboard pimcore-importer? Unfortunately it isn't supporting Localized Fields. So the only way is to write your own importer via the setter-methods. E.g.:

```php
foreach ($objectsToImport as $object) {

    foreach ($languages as $language) {
        $object->setFieldA($language);
        $object->setFieldB($language);
    }

    try {
        $object->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```